# How to access global variable in zend framework controller

Tags: zend-framework

I have Global Variable in .phtml file and i want to access that variable into the controller file of zend framework.

Comment: you ll have to pass that variable through $get or $post request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass variable through AJAX or URL and access variable by using get or post method in controller

Answer (score 0):

You can`t cause phtml files genelaly processed AFTER controllers methods.